# Feedback "To Do" List Visible/Editable by both Users and Developers

Tags: issue-tracker

I just started up a small online community, and I want to take advantage of the small and loyal userbase to influence the direction of the site I made.

I know of quite a number of apps and sites that can be used to coordinate between remote developers, but I'm looking for something of a list that my users can access where they can request whatever feature they want added/changed/removed. Preferably I would be able to "green light" or "red light" any suggestions and leave a comment explaining why something is a good idea/bad idea, or how long it will take to implement.

The reason for such an app or site is to reduce the amount of email I receive requesting changes, since many suggestions overlap. Does any of this sound familiar? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What budget do you have? Is your community somehow connected to open source? (which might help to get more free options)

Comment: Zero budget :) And though the source is technically open, I don't call it an "open source site".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Trello. Either you do it like they do it themselves and have a board were you put up suggestions that you receive via email and then your users can vote and/or leave comments but not create new proposals

https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ/trello-development

Trello also support emailing new card directly to a board so you could possibly set up some mail-proxy that creates a new card for all incoming suggestions on some "idea-board".

Or you could just create a trello board and invite everyone to edit everything on it if there aren't that many people.

Comment: Trello is working quite well for my purposes, thank you Spade.